# UITableView in xib file Swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift, xib

I am not using Storyboard's in my application, instead I am using xib files. My goal is to create an "Apple like" settings page in my app.

I would like to be able to insert an image and a label for each cell, then once the user has clicked the cell it would segue to the relevant view controller of my choice.

Also, it would be great to be able to use the grouping feature available in the UITableView.

I have seen how this is possible using a Storyboard, but I can't seem to find any information in using this feature in a xib file using Swift.

Thanks!